# Can I punch down regular hookup wire in an RJ45 Keystone Jack?

Tags: rj45

I'm planning to use CAT5e cable for a model railroad application and on the far end of the wire I am looking to use a keystone jack.  My question is whether or not regular hookup wire can be punched down in the keystone jack.

The specs on most jacks give the AWG size range and usually it runs from 22-26.  I tried punching down some 22 AWG solid wire in a jack and it was a real tight squeeze.  It made me question whether the jacks were only designed for CAT/UTP cable specifically and perhaps UTP wire had thinner insulation than other wire.

For my application, the low voltage (12v or less) and the low amperage (a few dozen milliamps) makes even 24 AWG wire oversized.  So I can certainly switch out and terminate 24 AWG wire into the keystone jack instead of the 22 I had already purchased.  But it will still be standard hookup wire and not CAT5e.  So again, would just like to know whether that is a concern or not.

As a secondary question, is stranded or solid going to be better for a punch down application like this?  My preference, given my situation is to use solid but I can work with stranded if that is going to be best.

Comment: If they keystone jack is an RJ-45 type, be sure to clearly label it.  Lots of things are using RJ-45 jacks now (Ethernet, POE Ethernet, CAN, etc...), and connecting the wrong device is usually damaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use any wire you are comfortable with. Since you are not using it for high speed comms it makes no difference what wire you use. Or just get some CAT5 cable and just peel the outer layer and you have pieces of rather compatible hookup wire. And usually infrastructure cabling is solid so the punch connections should work with solid wires.

Comment: As far as I know, keystone/punch down systems are designed for and work best with solid wire; there’s no need to use stranded wire.  Stranded wire is less prone to fatigue if the wire is moved close to the connector, but if you secure solid wires somehow you should have no problems.

Comment: Thanks, Justme.  No matter how hard I tried, I could just not find information anywhere about using RJ45 stuff with anything but CATx cable.  So I just wanted to make sure I was going to be ok using plain old hookup wire.

Comment: In my case, I will be soldering the other side of the wire that will be punched down to the RJ45 keystone jack, which is why I want to use solid hookup wire.  Maybe it's just the cheap CAT5e cable I have but I have not had a ton of success stripping the insulation off of the individual conductors.  Seems to be best reserved for IDC type connections.

Comment: Thanks, Frog, for the clarification about solid wire being fine/preferable.  I was hoping that was the case.